# How to match against ecto scheme integer types that act like enums

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Without using the Ecto enum library, what are other ways to match against integer values in the database that act like enums?

For example, in my schema I have this field:

```
field :account_status, :integer
```

So in my functions I want to know the meaning of the integer values 1,2,3 to translate too:

```
1 = VALID
2 = PENDING_CONFIRMATION
3 = CANCELLED
```

What options do I have?

The ones I can think of are:

```
def is_valid?(account)
  account.account_status == 1
end
```

And maybe storing the 1 in the ecto module for Account

```
defmodule Account do 
  @valid 2
end
```

Is this following best practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Erlang/Elixir we usually do pattern matching to accomplish this task.

```
def is_valid?(%{account_status: 1}), do: true
def is_valid?(_), do: false
```

---

Or, with a bit of metaprogramming:

```
defmodule M do
  @statuses %{
    valid: 1,
    pending_confirmation: 2,
    cancelled: 3
  }
  @field :account_status

  Enum.each(@statuses, fn {status, value} ->
    def unquote(:"is_#{status}?")(%{@field => unquote(value)}), do: true
    def unquote(:"is_#{status}?")(_), do: false
  end)
end

▶ M.is_valid? %{account_status: 1}
#⇒ true
▶ M.is_valid? %{account_status: 2}
#⇒ false
```

Comment: So these methods should go in my ecto model module right?

Comment: These methods could go wherever you find most suitable for them to go: model, helper, whatever module. If they are model-specific, I would put them into model.